# How to include karma reporter without publishing it as npm package

Tags: karma-runner

I want to use a self-written karma reporter which, however, is not intended to be published as a separate npm module. After reading both documentation and source code I'm still having hard times to figure out how exactly this should be done.

From code I see now this is sort of hardcoded in that sense that there's a one-to-one correspondence between the name of the reporter (say, "somereporter") and the name of npm package karma tries to refer to - in this case it's gonna be `karma-somereporter-reporter`.

Answer (score 0):

So, I finally figured it out. In order to add a local reported you need to include it as plugin, for instance:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({

    plugins: [
      require('../../MyReporter.js')
    ],


    reporters: ['myreporter']
  })
}
```